# Equivalent of FileReader for Java resources

Tags: java, resources, inputstreamreader

Is there a utility class (e.g. in commons-io or Guava, if not in core Java) that's the equivalent of `FileReader`, but for resources? I mean, yes, I can write

```
Reader myReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myResource"));
```

but it would be nice to do it with less boilerplate noise.

Comment: Why not just write your own utility class, put that code in it, and then use your new, shorter version?

Comment: Because if somebody's already done it I don't want to maintain it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no more concise what of writing this using core Java classes.

Guava has some [helpers for dealing with resources](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Resources.html), but nothing that wraps a resource as a `Reader`.

There is nothing relevant in Apache commons.

---

And in fact, what you've written is arguable wrong.  It depends on the platform character encoding being the same as the encoding of your embedded resources.  IMO, that is a more important issue than the amount of boiler plate code you need to write.

You can address the boilerplate "problem" by writing your own utility methods.

---

Re: this "reason" for not writing your own utility method.

> Because if somebody's already done it I don't want to maintain it myself.

Assuming that you write the method correctly, the maintenance effort will be almost zero.  And since (with the hint above) you now know how to write it correctly, the implementation effort will be almost zero too.  You've probably expended more effort looking for an existing helper (and asking here) than you would have saved ... if you'd found one.

Comment: +1 for the point about encodings... exactly the kind of reason I prefer NOT to write and maintain my own utility methods if there's an established project to do it for me.